# "Error: No operator "=" matches these operands"

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, operand

I'm having this weird problem where the compiler is highlighting "=" and "!=" as errors claiming that there are no matching operands but I have no idea how. Here's my code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Console.h"
#include "RandomNumber.h"
#include "Element.h"
#include "Flotsam.h"
#include "vector"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define NUMBER 10

int main()
{
    Console console;
    RandomNumber rnd;


    vector<Element*> flotsam;


    for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++)
    {
        flotsam.push_back(new Element(rnd, console));
    }

    vector<Element>::iterator ptr;

    ptr = flotsam.begin();

    while(ptr!=flotsam.end())
    {
        ptr->printAt();
        ptr++; 
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    console.clear();

}
```

Comment: `vector<Element*>` vs `vector<Element>`

Comment: I should mention that the only "=" and "!=" operators that are highlighted are after the "ptr"'s

Comment: Okay I removed the pointer from vector<Element>, now the "." is giving the error at flotsam.pushback

Comment: You need to add the pointer to the iterator declaration, or if you can use C++11 just use the `auto` keyword. `auto ptr = flotsam.begin()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your vector has a different type, the iterator should be

```
vector<Element*>::iterator ptr;
//            ^
```

Comment: Thanks, added that pointer. But now this part of the program: ptr->printAt(); is giving the error: must have pointer to class type

Comment: @user2288204 Make that `(*ptr)->printAt()`.

Answer (score 3):

`flotsam` is an `std::vector<Element*>`, so you need

```
vector<Element*>::iterator ptr;
```

You will also need to de-reference the pointer when accessing it via the iterator:

```
(*ptr)->printAt();
```

Alternatively, you can greatly simplify your code by using a vector of `Element` objects:

```
vector<Element> flotsam;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe even better solution would be (C++11):

```
auto ptr = flotsam.begin();
```

It will be stable against vector element type.

And yes, looking at iterator usage you probably should have:

```
vector<Element> flotsam;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the iterator type iterates over a `vector<Element>`, `flotsam` should also be a `vector<Element>`. There's no apparent need for a container of pointers here; a container of objects seems appropriate. To add elements, just use `pushback(Element(rnd, console))`; no `new` needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the changes now :)